# Proper use of access_token for Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, oauth

I'm extending the example.php from php-sdk in github. I'd like to list out the movies the user likes. $facebook->api('/me/movies') does not return results though the logged-in user has liked movies defined. I began to wonder if access_token was required.

Note, d is a simple print function:

```
<h3>Movie Likes</h3>
<?php d($facebook->api('/me/movies/?access_token=' . $session['access_token']))?>
```

Entering junk instead of the access_token has the same effect.

So - unclear if access_token is required or there is another problem. Secondly, if an access_token is needed is the the session access_token the one to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook's SDK already handles adding the access_token param to the call, you don't need to add it yourself. Have you already authenticated the user?

Does this return something?

```
print_r($facebook->getSession());
```

Comment: I have the same query. I get result for getSession() function. The user has authenticated the app and given permission. Now when i try to run the query for like, i get nothing.

Comment: same here, seems the generated access token does not properly work

Comment: Hey, did u find the solution i am facing the same problem.